# JavaScript! window.onload = someFunction and window.onload = someFunction()

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference between:

1. `window.onload = someFunction;`
2. `window.onload = someFunction();`

The parentheses at the end. Do they make any difference?

We generally use the first one! What if we Have to pass some parameter to the function. How will we do it by using the first statement?

Comment: If you have to pass a parameter you'd have to do `window.onload = function () {someFunction(someParameter);};`.

Comment: What parameter would you like to pass to this function?

Comment: not exactly to this function. i Want to pass some parameter to document.getElementNyId("something").onclick = someFunction(here I wanna pass something)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained otherwise, the first form

```
window.onload = someFunction
```

Simply set the "onload" variable to be equals to the "someFunction" function ; when the page finishes loading, this function is called.

The other form :

```
window.onload = someFunction()
```

Sets the "onload" variable to be the *result* of calling someFunction. Unless "someFunction" itself returns a function, this is probably not what you want to do.

By default, the onload function is called with a single "event" argument. If you want to pass arguments, you might be able to do something like this :

```
window.onload = function (event) {
  someFunction(someArg, someOtherArg)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your second statement assigns the **result** of `someFunction()` to `window.onload`.

If you want to add a parameter, you can do the following:

```
window.onload = function () {
    someFunction(parameter);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for simple example.

Answer (score 3):

`window.onload = someFunction;` assigns a function to `onload`.

`window.onload = someFunction();` **calls** a function and assigns its return value to `onload`. (This is not desirable unless the return value of that function is another function).

> What if we Have to pass some parameter to the function

Usually you define a new function which does nothing except call the original function with some arguments, then you assign the new function to the event handler.

Comment: nicely explained, thanks, the previous explanations escaped my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

if you use

```
window.onload = someFunction;
```

a function with the name of someFunction is called on window.onload

if you use

```
window.onload = someFunction();
```

someFunction() runs and the result is assigned to window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you put `window.onload = someFunction()` it is expected that the result of `someFunction()` is another function. This could be used for wrapping a function, or passing parameters. For instance:

```
window.onload = myFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

`myFunction(arg1, arg2)` would be expected to return some function incorporating these two variables.