# window.onload = someFunctionName vs window.onload = someFunctionName()

Tags: javascript

So the question is what is the difference between

`window.onload = someFunctionName` vs. `window.onload = someFunctionName()` and should I use this parentheses?

Comment: `window.onload=someFunctionName()` executes the function _right at that point_, and assigns whatever returned to `window.onload`, while `window.onload=someFunctionName` assigns the function itself to `window.onload`.

Comment: The latter would be assigning the result of the function (return value). The former would be just a reference to the function.

Comment: As stated before, the second form assign to the onload property the result of the someFunctionName execution, the first one the function itself. If you are reading written code then you should be aware that the result of a function can be a function by itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript! window.onload = someFunction and window.onload = someFunction()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526544/javascript-window-onload-somefunction-and-window-onload-somefunction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.onload = someFunctionName();` will **call** the `someFunctionName` function and **assign its return value** to the `onload` property.

`window.onload = someFunctionName;` assigns the `someFunctionName` function to the property `onload`. The browser will call that function when the `load` event occurs. Functions are objects. When you refer to them by their name *without* calling them, you're referring to the object.

Example:

```
window.onload = test();

function test() {
    alert("outer");
    return function(){
    alert("inner");
    }
}
```

this will alert twice as test() is called it will alert outer and return innerfunction to load and onload it will alert inner.

while

```
window.onload = test;

function test() {
    alert("outer");
    return function(){
    alert("inner");
    }
}
```

above code will only alert outer because innerfunction returned but never get called.

[Here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/8AWBQ/)

Comment: I would add that the result of a function can be a function

Comment: @Zaheer_Ahmed Oh, I don't need help (on this topic, at least). But I've seen several scripts broken by newbies for those parentheses removed without checking the result of the callad function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an excellent specification:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload

There are several ways to set it:
1.  Javascript, which requires setting it to a function.
2.  Setting it via an HTML tag as a string value.

Examples of both here and are valid ways.  I would recommend Javascript directly passing a function reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: This doesn't really address the difference between the two examples in the question.

Answer (score 1):

`window.onload = someFunction;` - assigns someFunction to onload event

`window.onload = someFunction();` - assigns a RESULT of someFunction to onload event.

Comment: Poor explanation, no offense. Plus, the text of the first explanation is directly above the second code block, so it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that [**in Javascript a function can return another function after execution**](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/usingfunctions-returningafunction-example.htm). For this reason, because you are not showing any code, both examples might be correct.

But there are differences between the two:

- `window.onload = someFunctionName` assigns the `someFunctionName` itself as the onload handler;
- `window.onload = someFunctionName()` does not assign the function `someFunctionName` itself but the returning result of the execution of the `someFunctionName` function. Assuming `someFunctionName` itself returns a function then it might be correct, otherwise you will get unexpected results.

Javascript functions are objects. When you use parentheses you are invoking the function. When you use the function without parentheses you are referring to the function object (i.e. the function itself).

So it depends on what you are doing...