# How to stop Canvas Image from disappearing even with onload event in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to put an Image in my webpage, but the image keeps disappearing the moment I hit the refresh button. I checked the other SO questions where it was mentioned that we had to add a line called `window.onload=yourDrawFunction()` , which I did, but I still have the problem. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Transformation Demo</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .hidden{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Tranformation Demo</h1>
        <img class = "hidden" id="goku" width="220" height="277" src="goku.jpg" alt="Goku Pic">
        <canvas id="surface" width=400 height=400>
            Your browser doesn't support canvas tag.
        </canvas>
        <script>
            function draw(){
                var drawing=document.getElementById("surface");
                var con=drawing.getContext("2d");
                var gokupic=document.getElementById("goku");

                con.save();
                con.translate(100,100);
                con.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
                con.scale(3.0,1.5);
                con.drawImage(gokupic, -25,-25,50,50);
                con.restore();

                con.strokeStyle="red";
                con.lineWidth=5;
                con.strokeRect(0,0,200,200);
            }
            window.onload=draw();
        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

Thanks

Note: My Image has no problems, but this works perfectly fine if I simply do this.
`window.onload=function(){
...
...
...
...}`

as opposed to giving my function a name called draw and then calling it. So why is this working and why isn't my draw() function working?

Comment: `window.onload=draw();` is executing `draw` right away, not assigning it, lose the `()`.

Comment: Hey thanks. It's working. Could you explain as to why I should remove ()? and also post it as an answer so that I can choose it as the right answer and close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation, why  `window.onload = someFunction()` is not working,  `window.onload = someFunction` works.

window.onload = someFunction()

Sets the "onload" variable to be the result of calling someFunction. Unless "someFunction" itself returns a function, this is probably not what you want to do.

By default, the onload function is called with a single "event" argument. If you want to pass arguments, you might be able to do something like this :

```
window.onload = function (event) {
  someFunction(someArg, someOtherArg)
}
```

For more details refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526544/javascript-window-onload-somefunction-and-window-onload-somefunction)