# Parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, events

When I try to call function like this window.onload=printLine;  All is OK.But When I use a parameter in the function like this window.onload=printLine(S) and use in the function (var iframeElementx = document.getElementById(s)) Nothing works.

Comment: If you have to pass a parameter you'd have to do window.onload = function () {printLine(S);};

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526544/javascript-window-onload-somefunction-and-window-onload-somefunction

Comment: Thank you.It was useful for me.